# Why are random sites linking to my site? What is their purpose?

Tags: statistics, bots, traffic, external-links

**In the "links from an external site" portion of my website statistics I see many sites that shouldn't have a reason to link to my site. Is there a reason for them doing this? Are they related in some way to spam/bots?**

For example, the sites supposedly linking to mine are sites like:

- ****-store(dot)com
- *****-imperia(dot)com
- handbags****(dot)com
- hunde****(dot)com
- iphone****(dot)com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply the victim of so called “Referral Spam” (fake referrer for various dirty online marketing reasons). For a first overview you could read  this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam) entry or learn how to fight against it here in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Referral%20Spam).